# Django set decimal separator depending on user browser settings

Tags: django, django-forms, localization, decimal

I would like to make decimal separator inside form in Django application dependend on user browser settings.

So if user has English leanguage then user should put

```
1.1
```

inside input form...

If language would be German, then user should put

```
1,1
```

inside  input form.

How do I achive this inside Djnago application.

P.S.

I am using the standard `CreateView` with `form_class`

inside the form class I have

```
fields = "__all__"
localized_fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Which field types are you using? DecimalField?

Answer (score 0):

In your apps's settings set:

```
USE_L10N = True
```

and in the templates

```
{% load l10n %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/formatting/

Comment: I have also set `LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', get_language_info('de')['name_local']),
    ('en', get_language_info('en')['name_local']),
)` - have you set any languages in the settings?

Comment: Yes I have LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
)